# Combine 'plainToClass' & 'validate' into one function as a generic in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, prisma, class-transformer

Here is my problem,

```
export const RegisterUser = async (request: Request): Promise<[number, UserResponse | { message: any }]> => {
     let userRequest = plainToClass(UserRequest, request.body);
     let errors = await validate(userRequest);
....
}
```

For every request, I have to write these two lines of code to map the object from the request body to the class object & need to validate manually, which is totally unnecessary. I want to achieve something like this,

```
let [userRequest,errors] = await ValidateRequest(UserRequest, request.body);
```

Where,

- I can pass any class as a parameter
- And the request body

But, I can't send the class as a parameter and also didn't get proper type suggestions in the return array. Here is a sample that I think that might be achievable,

```
export const ValidateRequest = async<T, V>(classObject: any, requestValue: any) : Promise<[T, ValidationError[]]>=> {
    let classValue = plainToInstance(classObject, requestValue);
    let errors = await validate(classValue)
    return [classValue, errors ];
};

Error: 

"Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.\n  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown[]'.",


Note : @deprecated — Function name changed, use the plainToInstance method instead.
```

Can you please help to figure out this ? TIA

Answer (score 1):

Reading `class-transformer` files, something like this should work.
They created a `ClassConstructor` to get the class of an element

```js
import { ClassConstructor, plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer'
import { validate, ValidationError } from 'class-validator'

export const ValidateRequest = async <T, V>(
  classObject: ClassConstructor<T>,
  requestValue: V[]
): Promise<[T[], ValidationError[]]> => {
  const classValue = plainToInstance(classObject, requestValue)
  const errors = await validate(classValue)

  return [classValue, errors]
}
```

Comment: I applied that but here the return type is T[] which make `Property 'email' does not exit on type UserRequest[]` I just need the return type UserRequest.

Comment: I tried another way, changed the return type T[] to T & make the cast classValue as T instead of T[] which was the default. Now It's getting proper autocompletion with the class where I used ValidRequest fn.